# c1841 unable to recognize HWIC-1T (smart serial) card. any idea?

Tags: cisco, ios

I have this problem where c1841 router unable to verify HWIC-1T card (with smart serial connector), you have to know that i have other routers with IOS
c1841-ipbasek9-mz.151-4.M5 and c1841-ipbasek9-mz.124-24.T5 on its flash and with ROM ver "Version 12.4(13r)T5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)" and those routers can recgonize the card succesfully so i just take the flash off from one of those routers and replace it with the flash of the router with the problem. i did some efforts as follows:

1.I have upgraded  ROM to "Version 12.4(13r)T5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)"

```
Green#show rom
ReadOnly ROMMON version:


System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(13r)T, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2006 by cisco Systems, Inc.


Upgrade ROMMON version:


System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(13r)T5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2007 by cisco Systems, Inc.


Currently running ROMMON from Upgrade region
ROMMON from Upgrade region is selected for next boot
```

2.I have upgraded IOS to c1841-ipbasek9-mz.151-4.M5.bin and c1841-ipbasek9-mz.124-24.T5.bin and still have the same problem.

3.I have entered the command show diag and i got the following:

```
Green#show diag


Slot 0:


    C1841 2FE 2SLOT Mainboard Port adapter, 2 ports
        Port adapter is analyzed
        Port adapter insertion time 02:49:58 ago
        EEPROM contents at hardware discovery:
        Chassis MAC Address      : 001b.d506.c8c8
        MAC Address block size   : 34
        PCB Serial Number        : FOC111909DY
        Hardware Revision        : 7.0
        Part Number              : 73-8191-08
        Board Revision           : A0
        Top Assy. Part Number    : 800-23434-06
        Deviation Number         : 0
        Fab Version              : 04
        CLEI Code                : IPM7W00CRA
        RMA Test History         : 00
        RMA Number               : 0-0-0-0
        RMA History              : 00
        Product (FRU) Number     : CISCO1841
        Version Identifier       : V05
        Processor type           : 86
        Chassis Serial Number    : FHK11191972
        EEPROM format version 4
        EEPROM contents (hex):
          0x00: 04 FF C3 06 00 1B D5 06 C8 C8 43 00 22 C1 8B 46
          0x10: 4F 43 31 31 31 39 30 39 44 59 40 04 1B 41 07 00
          0x20: 82 49 1F FF 08 42 41 30 C0 46 03 20 00 5B 8A 06
          0x30: 88 00 00 00 00 02 04 C6 8A 49 50 4D 37 57 30 30
          0x40: 43 52 41 03 00 81 00 00 00 00 04 00 CB 89 43 49
          0x50: 53 43 4F 31 38 34 31 89 56 30 35 20 D9 02 C1 40
          0x60: 09 86 C2 8B 46 48 4B 31 31 31 39 31 39 37 32 FF
          0x70: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x80: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x90: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0xA0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0xB0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0xC0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0xD0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0xE0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0xF0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x100: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x110: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x120: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x130: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x140: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x150: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x160: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x170: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x180: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x190: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x1A0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x1B0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x1C0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x1D0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x1E0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x1F0: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF


        WIC/HWIC Slot 0:
        Unknown WAN daughter card
        Unknown EEPROM ver 255
        EEPROM format version 255
        EEPROM contents (hex):
          0x20: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x30: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

3.these are show flash: outputs

Green#show flash:

```
-#- --length-- -----date/time------ path
1     27577580 Jan 02 2006 12:27:28 c1841-ipbasek9-mz.124-24.T5.bin
2         1038 Oct 11 2011 23:28:36 home.shtml
3         2746 Oct 11 2011 23:28:54 sdmconfig-18xx.cfg
4         5864 Feb 03 2013 22:16:54 PATCH9A45NVM.S37
5     34793740 Apr 03 2013 14:51:40 c1841-ipbasek9-mz.151-4.M5.bin


2736128 bytes available (62390272 bytes used)
```

4.these are show version outputs:

```
Green#show ver
Cisco IOS Software, 1841 Software (C1841-IPBASEK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T5, RELEAS
E SOFTWARE (fc3)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2011 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 04-Mar-11 02:48 by prod_rel_team


ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(13r)T5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)


Green uptime is 2 hours, 58 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 16:50:09 UTC Fri Apr 7 1972
System image file is "flash:c1841-ipbasek9-mz.124-24.T5.bin"




This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.


A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html


If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.


Cisco 1841 (revision 7.0) with 117760K/13312K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FHK11191972
2 FastEthernet interfaces
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity disabled.
191K bytes of NVRAM.
63808K bytes of ATA CompactFlash (Read/Write)


Configuration register is 0x2102
```

5.startup-config file attached.

6.I have entered boot system flash:c1841-ipbasek9-mz.151-4.M5.bin command for testing IOS c1841-ipbasek9-mz.151-4.M5.bin but you will not find it on configration file attached.

Any suggestion? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the exact same model card in the exact same model router with the exact same IOS as you have working other places, you could have a hardware issue.

Steal a module from another router that is known working.  Does it work okay in the new router?  If it does, probably an HWIC issue.

If other HWICs don't work either, do you have any other models that you could try in the new router to see if the slot is possibly bad?

Comment: I have tested the HWIC in other router and its work just fine. i will try another HWIC on the router and see what i can get, thank you.

Comment: I have tried another HWIC and i got the same problem i think the router have hardware problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would contact the place you bought the card from and request an RMA.

```
WIC/HWIC Slot 0:
    Unknown WAN daughter card
    Unknown EEPROM ver 255
    EEPROM format version 255
    EEPROM contents (hex):
      0x20: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
      0x30: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

All 1's in the EEPROM looks unrecoverably bad, and from [Cisco's website](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5949/datasheet_c78-491363.html) you're using code that should recognize that card.

Comment: well the card is working on newer router c1841, so what you think?

Comment: What is newer about the router it's working in(IOS/ROM/hw version)?  And what does the 'show diag' report for the card in the new router?  I guess you could try reseating it in the original router and make sure it's making good contact.

Comment: IOS & ROM versions are the same on both routers but the old one still have the problem and i did test the same card on both of them it does work on the new router but it does not work on the old one.

Comment: Does the HWIC work in the other slot on the 'problem' 1841?  If that works you could shine a light inside the broken slot and check for bent pins, or just skip that and RMA the whole thing.  It is a weird `show diag` output you posted, never seen one like that before.

Comment: In the other slot the router can't see anything at all.
What you mean by RMA?

Comment: If the problem 1841 is still under warranty or a support contract you should be able to return it for a replacement.  RMA means Return Merchandise Authorization, which refers to the fact you have to get the company to agree to replace/fix the broken device.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any HWIC cards working in any 1841's (I've got many!) on IOS Version 12. You need to upgrade to 15.

EDIT: Actually, I read your question wrong. I have this problem with HWIC-ADSL2 cards, not tried any 1T cards. Eitherway, I still stand by my post; upgrading to IOS 15 solves this for me every time.

Comment: As i said i replaced the flash of the older router with flash that comes with new routers and this flash contains IOS Version 15.1 and still have the same problem, so what you think?

Comment: I have had a look and one of them is running c1841-entbasek9-mz.150-1.M9.bin another is running c1841-broadband-mz.150-1.M8.bin. What IOS 15 did you try?

Comment: i tried c1841-ipbasek9-mz.151-4.M5.bin it does work on newer router but not on the old one.